# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Mainv1 Grouped.GroupMonth=V.GroupMonth

Tags: sql

I am trying to add another column in this query from another table.  I have added the table to reference however I am recieving an error message stating that I have a Syntx error (missing operator)in the SELECT expression

SELECT Mainv1Grouped.GroupMonth, Mainv1Grouped.TotalBk, V.ErrorCount, DOC.DocReviewErrors, V.ErrorCount/Mainv1Grouped.TotalBk AS ErrorPercent
FROM (SELECT Sum(mainv1.Number) AS TotalBk, DatePart("yyyy",[mainv1].[ProdDate],1,1) & "-" &                                 right('0'&              DatePart("m",[mainv1].[ProdDate],1,1),2) AS GroupMonth

FROM Mainv1
     WHERE (Mainv1.Department) in('AFS Booking')

AND 
   ((Mainv1.Function) in('AGR - MRE','AGR - NOT MRE','ASSUMP/PARTIC','AUTO BOOKED - B/C NRE','AUTO BOOKED - B/C RE','BCU - MRE','BCU - NOT MRE','BODP','COMM - MRE','COMM - NOT MRE','COMM FEE','GUIDANCE LINE','GUIDANCE LINE / LEASE LINE','L/C SECURED','L/C UNSECURED','MANUAL BOOKED - B/C RE','MANUAL BOOKED - B/C NRE','MODS','MODS - CAP LINES/CAP MGR/BEQL','MODS BOOK & REV','REBOOKS-OTHR','RETAIL','UNSEC - ALL'))

AND 
    datediff('m', [mainv1].[proddate], date())<13 GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[mainv1].[ProdDate],1,1) & "-" &                                 right('0'&           DatePart("m",[mainv1].[ProdDate],1,1),2))  AS Mainv1Grouped LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(DataV.ID) AS ErrorCount, DatePart("yyyy",[DataV].[Prod Date],1,1) & "-" &                                 right('0'&             DatePart("m",[DataV].[Prod Date],1,1),2) AS GroupMonth

FROM 
      DataV GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[DataV].[Prod Date],1,1) & "-" &                                right('0'&              DatePart("m",[DataV].[Prod Date],1,1),2))  AS V ON Mainv1 Grouped.GroupMonth = V.GroupMonth

AND

LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(DocReviewErrors.ID) AS ReviewErrorCount, DatePart("yyyy",[DocReviewErrors].[BookedDate],1,1) & "-" &                                 right('0'&             DatePart("m",[DocReviewErrors].[BookedDate],1,1),2) AS GroupMonth

FROM 
      DocReviewErrors GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[DocReviewErrors].[BookedDate],1,1) & "-" &                                right('0'&              DatePart("m",[DocReviewErrors].[Booked Date],1,1),2))  AS DOC ON Mainv1Grouped.GroupMonth = DOC.GroupMonth;

Comment: Please, format your question properly.

Comment: DATEPART only takes 2 arguments in SQL; you have 4?